# how to remove duplicate row values in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Hope all is well. i have a simple table with 4 rows as shown below. I want to remove row 2 and 4 from this table. the Data-->remove Duplicate works but it moves the rows up. is there a way i can keep the rows (not moving up)? Tried the Remove Duplicate but it removed the duplicate rows and moved the rest up.

```
Match Y/N   id      date        item    company
Y           6789    11/15/2020  phone   ZZY
Y           6789    11/15/2020  phone   ZZY
Y           6790    12/20/2020  phone   ZZY
Y           6790    12/20/2020  phone   ZZY


Match Y/N   id      date        item    company
Y           6789    11/15/2020  phone   ZZY
                
Y           6790    12/20/2020  phone   ZZY
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this from Stack Overflow and tested it and it works:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        Set rlook = Range(Cells(i - 1, "A"), Cells(1, 1))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rlook, Cells(i, "A")) > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "A").Clear
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```